# show count of rows between 2 dates

Tags: php, mysql, count

I am trying to show the number of rows that have a `created_at` date between 2 dates.

Here is my code:

```
$result=mysql_query("select * from payments 
                     where created_at between '2013/10/01 00:00:00' and '2013/10/30 00:00:00'") 
                     or die('You need to add an administrator ' );

$counter = mysql_query("select * from payments 
                        where created_at between '2013/10/01 00:00:00' and '2013/10/30 00:00:00'");

$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

$id = $row['id'];

$num = mysql_fetch_array($counter);
$countjan = $num["id"];
```

However  when i echo

```
<?php echo"$jan";?>
```

this shows as `0` any idea how i can get this to work

P.s there is 1 row within this date range

Comment: I hope I am not going blind, but where in your code is `$jan` referenced?  You tell us it is echo'd as 0, but where is assigned?

Comment: a valid DateTime should be 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS' or 'YYYYMMDDHHMMSS'

Comment: @demonking this hasn't made a difference

Comment: like AgRizzo says, what give <?php echo $countjan; ?> or where you get $jan from?

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM your_table WHERE created_at >= '2013/10/01 00:00:00' AND created_at <= '2013/10/30 00:00:00'`

Answer (score 0):

You can query like that:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM your_table WHERE created_at >= '2013/10/01 00:00:00' AND created_at <= '2013/10/30 00:00:00'
```

BTW: You should use MySQL date format or timestamp.

Comment: Between is created_at >= '2013/10/01 00:00:00' AND created_at <= '2013/10/30 00:00:00'

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE created_at >= '2013/10/01 00:00:00' AND created_at <= '2013/10/30 00:00:00'");
if($res)
{
$count=mysql_num_rows($res);
echo $count;
}
```